# Why can't I export an my object from a module/file (document) and import my object's functionality like the DOM (Document Object)?

Tags: javascript, object, import, module, export

For context, I am a beginner programmer and I'm currently doing a course to change my career as a delivery driver. I am presently learning about importing and exporting modules/files in JavaScript. I have only just learnt about named exporting/importing and default exporting/importing but I am struggling to intuitively understand why my object in my examples will not export/import correctly.

As mentioned above, I am new to this so I would really appreciate it if anyone could help provide clarity to me, and show me with alternative solutions how I can implement what I am trying to accomplish along with the core fundamental reasoning and logic as to why my examples are incorrect and not working...

In the examples that will follow I am trying to Export/Import an object from a module to use its functionality/methods (functions)... as well as find out what is best practice for exporting/importing modules/files.

So although I assume this is an unorthodox way of understanding, tackling, and explaining this problem... I used my current knowledge of the **Document Object Model (DOM)** and applied this same concept to what I am attempting to achieve. Therefore, I'd appreciate it if your answers could be from that same unorthodox perspective as much as you possibly can without making your solutions incorrect to make it easier for me and other beginners alike to understand as I know my logic and intuition is likely flawed. With that said, I apologise in advance if I butcher/neglect any paramount and fundamental concepts...

I'm finding it hard to understand why every imported module/file (**Document**) cannot just be seen as an exported **Object** to use and apply as one usually would use and apply a regular object such as the **Document Object** at the root node of the **DOM** tree structure?.. When using the **DOM** to access let us say for example an h1 element's style, you would type **document.h1.style**... So just like the word "document" is clearly the selected name of the object to access all HTML contents (an **Object** named "document" by the creators of JavaScript to access the contents of the **DOM/html-document-object**). Why is the same concept not applied to us importing/exporting a module/file (a **Document/module/file** named "yourObj" by yourself)...

## Let me explain...

## Example 1:

If I was to encapsulate my whole module/file (document) into one object and perform a named export on this object as follows:

```js
// In module.js
// Export Example 1:

const myObj = {
    exampleMethod1(num){
        num++;
        return num;
    },
    exampleMethod2(num){
        num--;
        return num;
    }
}

export {myObj};
```

and then when importing the above module/file (document/object) in Export Example 1, why does the following not work in main.js?

```js
// in main.js
// Import Example 1 (using Export Example 1):

import { myObj } from "./module.js";

var mainNum = 5;

myObj.exampleMethod1(mainNum);
```

As a beginner, I am expecting the above to work and work in the same way the DOM (document object) works... Or work in the same way that any other object works, for that matter?...

## Example 2:

And alternatively, I thought that the above Example 1 would effectively be the same as me default exporting the whole file/module as follows:

```js
// Alternatively in module.js
// Export Example 2:
const myObj = {
    exampleMethod1(num){
        num++;
        return num;
    },
    exampleMethod2(num){
        num--;
        return num;
    }
}

export default myObj;
```

And similarly, when importing the above module/file (document/object) in Export Example 2 in main.js, it doesn't work.

```js
// Alternatively in main.js
// Import Example 2 (using Export Example 2):
import myObj from "./module.js";

var mainNum = 5;

myObj.exampleMethod1(mainNum);
```

I was expecting to be able to use the presumably imported object (myObj) in main.js as I would within the module/file it originates from (module.js).

## Example Solution I found (but don't understand):

When looking at my course work I see that this is their solution:

```js
// In module.js
// A Correct Export Solution:
const exampleFunction1 = (num) => {
    num++;
    return num;
};
 
const exampleFunction2 = (num) => {
    num--;
    return num;
};
 
const myObj = { 
  exampleFunction1, 
  exampleFunction2
}
export default myObj;

// In main.js
// A Correct Import Solution (using the above Correct Export Solution):
import myObj from './module.js'

const {exampleFunction1, exampleFunction2} = myObj; 
// I have no idea what is happening on this above line... Seems counter-intuitive to have to 
// copy/remember all functionality by name and then assign it to myObj (presumably again)?
// What happens if there are 100s or even 1000s of functions/data... would you have to 
// assign each function's/data-points name in the same way?...

var mainNum = 5;

exampleFunction1(mainNum); // No use of 'myObj' prefix?...
```

**I have no clue why the above works and find it counter-intuitive to think that I would need to remember/copy the names of all functions and assign them to the default variable again once it has been imported... even though I presumably already exported the whole of my module.js file as myObj?... Please help!**

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you are creating a new Object in your export statement.

```js
export {myObj};
// which is a shorthand form and equivalent to:
export {myObj: myObj};
```

Then you would have to access the functions like this:

```js
import myObj from "./module.js";
myObj.myObj.exampleMethod1();
```

You probably meant to do this: (without the extra braces)

```js
export myObj;
```